# Java key stores, SSL and CAS

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, keystore, cas

I overheard a conversation where 2 developers were talking about an authentication system they were building and they were talking about a Java "key store" and also mentioned a "CAS server" as well as SSL. I went to the JASIG CAS website and it seems that its used for authentication systems where you want to control user logins and sessions. It seems that the Java keystore is a file (an embedded DB perhaps?) that stores encrypted CA certificates.

I'm trying to figure out how these 3 technologies could be used together to create a secure, Java-based authentication system.

So would a web app use the CAS client (in my case Java) to communicate with a running instance of the CAS server? If so, where and how do the keystore and SSL cert snap into the architecture? Does CAS store the SSL cert in the keystore, and then use it with the backend directory (ActiveDirectory, etc.) somehow? Can someone just give me a high-level overview of how this would all come together?

Comment: The Java KeyStore is a file that stores encrypted private keys or non-encrypted certificates.

Comment: Thanks @EJP (+1) - would SSL be an encrypted or non-encrypted cert (basically, would the KeyStore be used to store an SSL cert)? Why or why not?

Comment: A certificate is a public document. There's no sense in encrypting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAS central authentication is largely orthogonal to SSL and its keystores and certificating authorities.  CAS is a way to allow multiple services to share one authentication server, so users can sign on only once at a central authentication server.  Connections to the services and the central authentication server can of course be encrypted using SSL, just like other network connections.  Using SSL necessitates the use of keystores and trust stores to store the keys and trust certificates, including CA - certificating authority - certificates.

Comment: Thanks @Warren Dew (+1) - a few followup questions: (1) what is the difference between a "keystore" and a "trust store"? As EJP stated, a keystore is where private keys or non-encrypted certs are stored. If that's true, then what's the purpose of the *trust* store? And (2) What are the relationships between CAS and each type of store? In other words, what does CAS use both of these for? Thanks again!

Comment: The key store is where the private keys are kept.  The trust store is where the public certificates of the entities that one trusts are kept.  The way SSL works, one side of the transaction - typically the client - has a trust store, and the other side - typically the server - has a key store.  The server presents its certificate, and uses its private key to prove that the certificate really belongs to it.  The client checks that the public certificate is trusted.

Comment: Oops, can't use paragraphs in comments.  In the case of CAS, both the CAS server and the web servers would have their own key stores.  The client would need to have a trust store that included the certificates of the CAS server and the web servers.  Note that sometimes, especially in java, the same file is used as both a key store and a trust store, which is why java has a "keytool" that handles both.